# Master PivotTable Filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table, excel-2013

I have 6 pivot-charts on many worksheets (each worksheet corresponding to different individuals), all pivot-tables have a Month filter. Instead of clicking on each individual filter to update the pivot-table (and corresponding pivot-chart). Is there a way of creating a 'master' filter button so that all filters are updated?

Let me know if you require further information.

Comment: Whatever way works really, I've added VBA to the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a [slicer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-slicers-to-filter-PivotTable-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d). Slicers are similar to filters, but look a little different and can be associated with multiple pivot tables. This means you might want to make a "front page" or similar area with the slicer on it so it is obvious that the one slicer controls the month filter for all pivot tables.

You just insert the slicer on the page, then click on Report Connections and connect it to each pivot table.

Comment: Thanks for this @mmarie . Is there a way of selecting all the connections without ticking each on individually in the Report Connections?